How to get customize ranking in pbi



Market
Date
Points_SA
Rank
Output




Texas
4/16/2024
1
1
1


Miami
4/16/2024
0.7
2
2


Philadelphia
4/16/2024
0.7
2
2


North Carolina
4/16/2024
0.7
2
2


New York
4/16/2024
0.6
3
5


New England
4/16/2024
0.6
3
5


New Jersey
4/16/2024
0.6
3
5


Los Angeles
4/16/2024
0.5
4
8


Washington DC
4/16/2024
0.5
4
8


San Francisco
4/16/2024
0.3
5
10


California
4/16/2024
0.1
6
11


Texas
4/17/2024
1
1
1


Miami
4/17/2024
0.7
2
2


Philadelphia
4/17/2024
0.7
2
2


North Carolina
4/17/2024
0.7
2
2


New York
4/17/2024
0.6
3
5


New England
4/17/2024
0.6
3
5


New Jersey
4/17/2024
0.6
3
5


Los Angeles
4/17/2024
0.6
3
5


Washington DC
4/17/2024
0.5
4
9


San Francisco
4/17/2024
0.3
5
10


California
4/17/2024
0.1
6
11


Texas
4/18/2024
1
1
1


Miami
4/18/2024
0.7
2
2


Philadelphia
4/18/2024
0.7
2
2


North Carolina
4/18/2024
0.6
3
4


New York
4/18/2024
0.6
3
4


New England
4/18/2024
0.6
3
4


New Jersey
4/18/2024
0.6
3
4


Los Angeles
4/18/2024
0.5
4
8


Washington DC
4/18/2024
0.5
4
8


San Francisco
4/18/2024
0.3
5
10


California
4/18/2024
0.2
6
11



Hi everyone,
i have this table with desired ranking output column
rank based on  points_SA (desc) and rerank every date change.
dax formula below is working but not giving me the desired output.
note: points_SA is a measure
appreciate the help!! thanks in advance
Rank_SA_pt =
RANKX(
    FILTER(
        ALL(date),
        [Points_SA] <> BLANK() && [Points_SA] <> 0
    ),
    [Points_SA],
    , DESC, Dense)


In your measure replace Dense with Skip:
Rank_SA_pt = RANKX( FILTER( ALL(date), [Points_SA] <> BLANK() && [Points_SA] <> 0 ), [Points_SA], , DESC, Skip)


Market Id Pts_SA R_dense R_skip desired output
texas  1 1 1 1
Miami  0.7 2 2 2
Philadelphia 0.7 2 3 2
North Carolina 0.7 2 4 2
New York 0.6 3 5 5
New England 0.6 3 6 5
New Jersey 0.6 3 7 5
Los Angeles 0.5 4 8 8
Washington DC 0.5 4 9 8
San Francisco 0.3 5 10 10
California 0.1 6 11 11

example texas is rank 1 and maimi,phili,NC are rank 2 (.7). ranking for ny, nj, & NE should be 5 will count all previous ranked 4 markets

It seems to me that the problem is solved. Skip rank and Desired Output rank are matching. did I understand correctly?

Your ranking should be like below :
Output = 
RANKX(
    FILTER(
        ALL('MyTable'),
        'MyTable'[Date] = EARLIER('MyTable'[Date])
    ),
    'MyTable'[Points_SA],
    ,
    DESC,
    Dense
)


